# I can't create a React element by hand typing literal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created 2 React elements: first is created traditionally, using react.createElement and second element - by hand typing literal(for educational purpose). I heard that React element is just a js object.
First is rendering fine. Second is causing error.

Error: ReactDOM.render(): Invalid component element. This may be caused by unintentionally loading two independent copies of React.

What is wrong with second React element?

```js
<script>


var first = React.createElement("h1", null, "Important Announcement");

var second = 
{
$$typeof: Symbol(React.element),
"type": "h1",
"key": null,
"ref": null,
"props": {"children": "Important Announcement"},
"_owner": null,
"_store": {}
}

ReactDOM.render(first, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```

Comment: Try amending this line: $$typeof: Symbol.for('react.element')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `$$typeof` definition to `$$typeof: Symbol.for('react.element')` should fix your issue.

React requires it for security reasons as mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html).

Please have a look at the demo below or this [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/decotoq/edit?html,js,output).

```js
var first = React.createElement("h1", null, "Important Announcement");

var second = {
  $$typeof: Symbol.for('react.element'),
  "type": "h1",
  "key": null,
  "ref": null,
  "props": {
    "children": "Important Announcement"
  },
  "_owner": null,
  "_store": {}
}

console.log(first, second)
ReactDOM.render(second, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.1.0/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.1.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```